# How to document a $this in a Laravel Macro Closure?

Tags: php, laravel, closures, documentation, phpdocumentor2

Suppose I have a **Macro** registered in my package ServiceProvider and I am writing documentation for my package.

```php
\Laravel\Dusk\Browser::macro('scrollToElement', function ($element = null) {
    $this->script("$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('$element').offset().top }, 0);");

    return $this;
});
```

Now how do I document the variable `$this` in the **Closure**?

Comment: In what respect?

Comment: `\Laravel\Dusk\Browser`

Comment: Ok. What part of it are you struggling with? Is it how to explain what `$this` in this context actually is, or is it explaining how it works?

Comment: how to explain what $this in this context .